# Magento 2.3.6 - Img and SKU or product ID SQL dump

Tags: database, magento2.3.6

I need a SQL dump in CSV where I get these values:

IMG name
SKU or product ID

I use PHPAdmin and looking through the tables but can't find any values where I can link the tables to get the info I need. Anyone know what I can do? or have a script I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so will post how I did it here.

(Mind that I used PHPAdmin and not ssh)

I used the row called value_id in catalog_product_entity_meadia_gallery and the row value_id in catalog_product_entity_meadia_gallery_value to get the enity_id so I could add SKU to the catalog_product_entity_meadia_gallery.